# Code with line numbers in RestructuredText is not rendered on Github

Tags: github, restructuredtext

Consider the following RestructuredText formatted fike file, which can be created in a repository on Github (e.g. as `test.rst`):

```
::

    This is a basic literal block
    whose formatting is preserved

.. code-block:: python

    def foo():
        print("you don't say")

.. code:: python

    def foo():
        print("you don't say")

.. code-block:: python
    :linenos:

    def foo():
        print("you don't say")

.. code:: python
    :number-lines:

    def foo():
        print("you don't say")
```

In Github, only the first three literal blocks are displayed:

```
This is a basic literal block
whose formatting is preserved

def foo():
    print("you don't say")

def foo():
    print("you don't say")
```

The two code blocks with line numbers (using either the Sphinx directive `code-block` or the vanilla docutils directive `code`) are neither displayed by Github.

My questions:

- Is there a workaround, so that they are at least shown (even without line numbers)?
- If this is a bug (I suspect so), where can I report it? I can't find a restructeredtext library github is using in https://github.com/github/.

Comment: GitHub does not seem to run a full previewer of reStructuredText, so I don't think all features wanted are there (yet).

Comment: I usually use MarkDown these days, but reStructuredText is still useful for Python documentation. Any clue where to report issues like this?

Comment: https://support.github.com/ Contact them directly.